# Switch input language on remote application

Tags: windows, winapi, localization, keyboard

Is it possible to switch input language for another application? Having application's process ID, thread ID, window handle etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [LoadKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305(VS.85).aspx) and [ActivateKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289(VS.85).aspx) ?

Comment: I know about these API, however I'm trying to change input language for _another_ application having HWND only.

Comment: You can use these functions in a DLL and inject this DLL in the process you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's been asked before.

[Is there a WinXP/WinXP Embedded API to change Locale (specifically, IME)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819483/is-there-a-winxp-winxp-embedded-api-to-change-locale-specifically-ime)

Though it is Windows Embedded, the API is probably the same or similar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry but the question is totally different. It shows how to change system-wide locale. I'm trying to switch input language for specific application only.