# Change input language of another application

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, keyboard, input-language

I want to change the input language of the active window.
The problem is that the active window is not my application.
I know about `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;` but it changes the language for my WinForms application and not for the active application.

Summary: my situation is that my program listens to any keyboard event (even when
it's not focused) and executes code when I press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

I want this press on <kbd>F1</kbd> to change the language to Hebrew in Notepad which was the active application when I pressed F1.

I am interested in either a low level solution or a high level solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch input language on remote application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261494/switch-input-language-on-remote-application)

Comment: Using F1 for anything else than launching help for the current application is probably unexpected for the user.

Answer (score 2):

You should know another application's `hWnd` and post a message for it

```
    public void InputLangChangeRequest(IntPtr hwnd, InputLanguage language)
    {
        IntPtr handle = InputLanguage.Handle;
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, handle);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of this [Switch input language on remote application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261494/switch-input-language-on-remote-application)

This reference can also help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947