# How does Default Input Language Switcher work in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language-switching, input-language

Default input languages switcher listens for key strokes and changes input language of any application. How does it happen? Does it use `DLL` injection as described in comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261532/258483 or there are any other means?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's how the switcher does this, but if you want to do something similar for your application, you can use [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

```
BOOL RegisterHotKey(
  HWND hWnd,
  int  id,
  UINT fsModifiers,
  UINT vk
);
```

It allows you to ask for a notification when a certain combination of keys is hit, no matter what window has focus.